# How do I configure DATABASE_URL to add a list of host_names to database.yml on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, discourse

Heroku generates database.yml from the DATABASE_URL environment variable like so: https://gist.github.com/liliakai/c161ad5704be04e88999

I'd like the resulting database.yml to include the line

```
host_names:  
  - my.customdomain.com
```

How would I encode this into the query string on the DATABASE_URL?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You can add things to the database url by manually setting the environment variable, but there are few good reasons to do this.

Comment: I'm running Discourse which looks for this config in database.yml.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set attributes on the `DATABASE_URL` like so

```
$ heroku config:get DATABASE_URL
[copy returned value]
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=[paste value]?host_names=my.customdomain.com
```

**Note that this is fragile**; promoting a new database, or reseting the credentials, will reset the `DATABASE_URL`. These kinds of additions will also cause the Heroku pgbackups add-on to not work.

Finally, this is not required for Discourse on Heroku – I just setup Discourse myself and didn't need it.

Comment: Perhaps not, but it was suggested as a possible fix for http://meta.discourse.org/t/password-length-error-when-registering-with-social-account/4670/21

Comment: I think your answer will result in host_names: my.customdomain.com all on one line. Not sure if this will work with discourse which looks at something like config[:host_names].first

Comment: Can you register new users using one of the social network logins?